# Generating quadtree within d3.timer causes stack overflow

Tags: d3.js

Having a strange issue generating quadtrees within `d3.timer`. The following code for generating a quadtree throws no errors:

```
var tree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
```

But I'm using the tree for collision detection similar to [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298). The big difference is I'm not using a force layout, so instead of generating the tree within `force.on('tick')`, I'm trying to do it with the timer:

```
d3.timer(function() {
   var tree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
});
```

This throws a stack overflow error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I can't understand why this is happening, but it seems to have something to do with JS's timing mechanism. Generating the quadtree within a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` causes the same error, even with very slow intervals. Generating thousands within a loop works fine.

Anyone have any insight into what's going on? Am I doing something dumb, or should I be submitting an issue on d3's GitHub?

Comment: You schedules a new timer, invoking the specified function repeatedly until the timer is stopped. You create all new tree instance, over and over again. At some point you'll run out memory

Comment: Don't think that's it. The quadtree is overwritten each time. Also, I was being dumb. My X and Y were stored as strings, which was causing the unexpected behavior. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave this up in case anyone runs into something similar, but the issue was caused by the `point.x` and `point.y` values being stored as strings instead of numbers, and that was causing unexpected behavior.

So it turned out I was being dumb after all, though it is still a mystery as to why it only caused errors when run within timeout functions.